# How do I get the user's screen resolution in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs3

Is there a way ActionScript 3 can detect the user's screen resolution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have a look at `stage.fullScreenHeight` and `stage.fullScreenWidth`

Answer (score 14):

These will return the numbers to your output window:

```
trace(Capabilities.screenResolutionX);
trace(Capabilities.screenResolutionY);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on AIR, you could use the `flash.display.Screen` class, which contains this info, plus a lot more, such as color-depth, and multi-screen support.

Answer (score 1):

`flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionY` and `flash.system.Capabilities.screenResolutionX`