# Can I change the fullscreen scaling algorithm in Flash when using fullScreenSourceRect?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, fullscreen, hardware-acceleration

When I put my Flash game into full screen interactive display mode and set stage.fullScreenSourceRect so that it uses hardware scaling, the performance at any resolution seems to be much better than if I do it without the fullScreenSourceRect. I'd really like to use this feature, but the problem is that it seems to be using a 4x blur or some similar algorithm for scaling that leaves everything looking very blurry.

It seems like an odd choice to have a blur as the only available scale mode. I would be much happier with a simple nearest-neighbor. I can't find anything about changing the scale algorithm in the documentation. Is there any way to do this while still using hardware acceleration?

Comment: I think you'll always get the blur to some degree because of the variable resolutions out there that it has to scale to.  You could have some target resolutions (most common) and make your native width/height be half that, or use the system.capabilities class to get the actual screen resolution and set your window to that size.

Comment: Thanks LondonDrugs, but when hardware acceleration is used there is a blurry scaling effect even if the fullScreenSourceRect is exactly half the width and height of the full screen size. The problem isn't distortion due to variable resolution, the problem is a blurry scaling algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

What is the intended platform for this game? If this is mobile, then there are standards that can be implemented to ensure the ideal resolutions. If this is for web then, I would recommend defining rigid dimensions. Otherwise in my experience, its best to develop to your display's ideal native resolutions. Unless you have your code dynamically drawing objects to your stage, the  there will always be some kind of rastering/interpolation. You can also get your screens resolutions and have the code make adjustments accordingly:  [How do I get the user's screen resolution in ActionScript 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048566/how-do-i-get-the-users-screen-resolution-in-actionscript-3)

I've developed a lot of touch screen applications that span multiple displays with different resolutions and AIR has some great options in it's 'Screen' class to make the process easier.

Comment: Hi. It's a browser game. Thanks for your answer but I don't think you understood the question. Getting the screen resolution isn't the problem. It's already working just fine using software scaling in fullscreen mode. The problem is that I would like to use hardware acceleration to do the scaling for a performance boost. Flash has a built-in feature to do that, and I am asking if there is a way to change the scaling algorithm it uses to something sharper than 4x blur.